# how to calculate array differece in Jmeter Bean Shell post processor

Tags: jmeter

I've a scenario like

- user1 logs in
- get all its reservation ids through json path extractor and store in array1
- user2 logs in
- get all its reservation ids through json path extractor and stores in array2

Now I need the array3 which would be the value in array1 but should not be in array2. What code I need to write in Bean shell post processor in Jmeter for javascript?

**Example:**

```
array1 = ["75457052","75405285","75400251","75400246","1YQWAY", "1233456", "678878989",  "7979877877"]
array2 = ["75457052","75405285","75400251","75400246","75400252","75307496","75307497","75307498"]
```

Once I find the array3, then I would put the logic like if the length of array3 > 1 then pick the first index of that array and navigate to that reservation-id.

Comment: function arrayDiff(a1, a2) {
     var o1={}, o2={}, diff=[], i, len, k;
    for (i=0, len=a1.length; i<len; i++) { o1[a1[i]] = true; }
     for (i=0, len=a2.length; i<len; i++) { o2[a2[i]] = true; }
      for (k in o1) { if (!(k in o2)) { diff.push(k); } }
      for (k in o2) { if (!(k in o1)) { diff.push(k); } }
      return diff;
      }
    var a1 =  ["75457052","75405285",];
    var a2 = ["75457052","75405285"];
    vars.put ("a3",arrayDiff(a1, a2));
This gives difference only but not the one which is part of array1 and should not be part of array2

Comment: Got the answer
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return !(a.indexOf(i) > -1);});
};

var a1 = ["75457052","75405285","75400251","75400246","75400252","75307496","75307497","75307498"];

var a2 = ["75457052","75405285","75400251","75400246","75400252","75307496","75307497","75307498"];

var a3 = a1.diff( a2);

vars.put ("id",a3[0]);

vars.put ("a3",a1.diff( a2));